# How can I switch to address in list connected address in metamask?

Tags: metamask

I am facing an issues that: If user in account A want to sign message of account B. How can I switch to account B and popup sign message?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible via MetaMask. You can do that programmatically though, by creating the respective `signers` corresponding to **account A**  & **account B**. Then, use one signer to sign the transaction, and the other one to send the signed transaction.

Comment: I found a solution in https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/how-to/sign-data/siwe/. You can pass address in personal_sign.